# How to find this checksum using Java

Tags: java

To find this particular checksum, we need to sum the digits of the input and multiply by 2. Simple enough by finding the remainder using a loop.

If the result is less than 10, that is the number's checksum. If it is 10 or higher, we need to do it again until the result is less than 10.

If it gets caught in an infinite loop, such as with the input of 18, return -1.

This is what I have so far:

```
public int getChecksum(int input, int previous) {
        int sum = 0;

        while (input > 0) {
            sum += input % 10;
            input /= 10;
        }
        if (sum * 2 < 10) {
            return sum * 2;
        } else if (sum * 2 >= 10 && previous != sum) {
            previous = sum;
            return getChecksum(sum * 2, previous);
        } else if (previous == sum) {
            return -1;
        }
        return sum * 2;
    }
```

I really wanted to know if there was a way to do this without doing it recursively as I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple recursive algorithm like this can also be implemented iteratively. Usually you would go about this turning the recursive call into a loop with the recursive termination condition as the loop termination condition.